# Cannot start program. Pocketsphinx.dll is missing error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have set additional library directories and lib folders to be used in visual studio. Also build succeeded but whenever I try to execute the program from Visual Studio it returns the following error:

> The program can't start because pocketsphinx.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix problem.

When I checked the directories, I saw that `pocketsphinx.dll` was there.

My code is (taken from `pocketsphinx` wikia):

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>

#define MODELDIR "C:\Sphinx\pocketsphinx\model" 
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ps_decoder_t *ps;
cmd_ln_t *config;
FILE *fh;
char const *hyp, *uttid;
int16 buf[512];
int rv;
int32 score;

config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
             "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
             "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
             "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
             NULL);
if (config == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create config object, see log for details\n");
    return -1;
}

ps = ps_init(config);
if (ps == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create recognizer, see log for details\n");
    return -1;
}

fh = fopen("goforward.raw", "rb");
if (fh == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file goforward.raw\n");
    return -1;
}

rv = ps_start_utt(ps);

while (!feof(fh)) {
    size_t nsamp;
    nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
    rv = ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
}

rv = ps_end_utt(ps);
hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, &score);
printf("Recognized: %s\n", hyp);

fclose(fh);
ps_free(ps);
cmd_ln_free_r(config);

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** `pocketsphinx.dll` is in `bin\Debug\x64` folder as like as `pocketsphinx.lib`.

Comment: "I saw that pocketsphinx.dll was there." Where is there?

Comment: I assume the executable for your project (which you are building in the x64 Debug configuration) is not in `bin\Debug\x64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your program in a debugger in Visual Studio your Working Directory parameter (Project Settings->Configuration Properties->Debugging) is `$(ProjectDir)` by default. Change it to `$(TargetDir)` and it should start.